# NASM trying to multiply integer by float, printf writes garbage

Tags: assembly, nasm, x87

I tried creating a very simple example: a conversion program, where one number is an int and the other is a double.

```
global _main
extern _printf

section .data
    km_h    dd  70
    format  db '%fmph=%dkm/h',10,13,0
    km_mi   dq 1.609

section .code
_main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    
    sub esp, 16 ;for the parameters
    
    fld qword [km_mi]
    fimul dword [km_h]
    
    mov dword [esp], format
    mov eax, dword [km_h]
    mov [esp+12], eax
    fstp qword [esp+4]
    push format
    call _printf
    
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I tried cc -S on a C source and went as far as writing it with mov `[esp+X]` instead of `push`ing, but whatever I try, it outputs garbage.

Comment: Why do you have both `mov dword [esp], format` and `push format` ?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot and didn't notice that I left a push there after all... it's very likely the cause, I'll remove it...

Comment: Also you got the conversion (or the printing) reversed.

Comment: I reversed the variable names I guess when translating source to English to make it understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've removed the `push` and it works now. The conversion is still backwards, but that's easy to fix, and of course, that didn't really matter, it was just a homework to practice the opcodes.